# Referring a component bean in XML - Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations, autowired

I have a bean A that's annotated as Component. I am creating a map in Spring Config XML with the bean A as one of the values in the map. Is there anyway i can avoid creating the bean A in the config xml and just refer as it is annotated as Component.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All annotated components will be available with the same class name (camelCase) by default. I think you can use that name in the XML file.

```
<property name="taskList">
        <list>
            <ref bean="componetClass1" /> 
            <ref bean="componetClass2" />
            <ref bean="componetClass3" /> 
            <ref bean="componetClass4" />         
        </list>
    </property>
```

In this case ComponentClass1 etc are the class names which are annotated with @Component annotation.

Comment: I suggest actually giving it a `@Component` name to avoid ambiguity.